# Select attributes on repository.find() with relations (TypeORM)

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

My method returns a a bill object with all of User object.
I would like that I return only bill object and User with two attributes in entity. I use TypeORM

```
  /**
   * Returns a bills by account bill
   */
  async getByAccountBill(
    accountBill: string,
    id?: number
  ): Promise<Object | undefined> {
    const userService = new UserService();
    const user = await userService.getById(id);

    const bills = await this.billRepository.find({
      select: ["accountBill"],
      where: {
        accountBill: Like(`${accountBill}%`),
        user: Not(`${user.id}`)
      },
      relations: ["user"] // I get All object Entity (userId, password, login...) I want to only name and surname
    });

    if (bills) {
      return bills;
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use querybuilder which is one of the most powerful tool of TypeOrm, to do so.

```
const values = this.billRepository.createQueryBuilder("bill")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("bill.user", "user")
    .where("bill.accountBill LIKE :accountBill", {accountBill})
    .andWhere("user.id = :userId", {userId: user.id})
    .select(["user.name", "user.surname"])
    .execute();
```

```
// NOTE
// .execute() will return raw results.
// To return objects, use .getMany()
```

Comment: The 'execute' method return a raw result, so maybe for you is better to use getMany thats return an object

Comment: Hey @zenbeni, I am trying to do somethiing similar but it would return `undefined` if there is no user and `andWhere` condition fails. How do we make same query work if there are no entries in relation table yet?

Comment: The question explicitly mentioned find() method. We want to rely on the wiring we have already done in the model. Query builder is a powerful tool, but it should only be employed in complex queries where model wiring isn't enough in my opinion. The question include a simple query.

Comment: @hadaytullah you can't use basic model wiring, as getting only 2 fields in User is completely out of the vanilla model which includes much more fields. You have to use custom query to object mapping to do so. Thus, query builder, this is for me the correct tool.

Comment: Since  typeOrm  lack applying selection on a joined table, we can use typescript Array.map()  to remove unnecessary attributes from the collection. It is not a wise solution if the collection is too large. But at the same time, such mapping is anyway happing on the database server if we use query builder with that selection included in the query. So, we just moved that processing from DB server to the API server. The response time would be a good metric to decide which solution find+Array.map VS querybuilder is good for your app.

Comment: Data is where the performance is, you imply more network usage with your proposed solution, more I/O on database as you fetch more data than you need (I/O and network are in most cases more critical than any in-memory algorithm optimizations). Also you add non vanilla usage of data structures & TypeOrm with custom code that you will have to maintain afterwards (opposed to classic querybuilder api usage). Removing column data after having fetched them explicitely on the database is suboptimal at best and should be avoided performance wise.

Comment: It is typeORM modeling limitations that led to usage of query-builder or vanilla code. I guess once the models allow more complex joins, there would be no need for them. Sequalize is a bit more mature ORM and many complex joins can be done.

Answer (score 42):

It's bit late but for all others who visit this page may be helpful
there is a option available in `typeorm` so we can get the result how we want.

```js
return this.repository.find({
  relations: ['user'],
  loadRelationIds: true,
  where: { ... },
  order: { ... }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case someone interested, short list of code related to relation and links to repo...

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/find-options/FindOptionsUtils.ts

```
    /**
     * Applies give find options to the given query builder.
     */
    static applyOptionsToQueryBuilder<T>(qb: SelectQueryBuilder<T>, options: FindOneOptions<T> | FindManyOptions<T> | undefined): SelectQueryBuilder<T>;
...
        if (options.loadRelationIds === true) {
            qb.loadAllRelationIds();
        }
        else if (options.loadRelationIds instanceof Object) {
            qb.loadAllRelationIds(options.loadRelationIds);
        }
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts

```
/**
 * Loads all relation ids for all relations of the selected entity.
 * All relation ids will be mapped to relation property themself.
 * If array of strings is given then loads only relation ids of the given properties.
 */
loadAllRelationIds(options?: { relations?: string[], disableMixedMap?: boolean }): this { // todo: add skip relations
    this.expressionMap.mainAlias!.metadata.relations.forEach(relation => {
        if (options !== undefined && options.relations !== undefined && options.relations.indexOf(relation.propertyPath) === -1)
            return;

        this.loadRelationIdAndMap(
            this.expressionMap.mainAlias!.name + "." + relation.propertyPath,
            this.expressionMap.mainAlias!.name + "." + relation.propertyPath,
            options
        );
    });
    return this;
}

/**
 * LEFT JOINs relation id and maps it into some entity's property.
 * Optionally, you can add condition and parameters used in condition.
 */
loadRelationIdAndMap(mapToProperty: string, relationName: string, options?: { disableMixedMap?: boolean }): this;

/**
 * LEFT JOINs relation id and maps it into some entity's property.
 * Optionally, you can add condition and parameters used in condition.
 */
loadRelationIdAndMap(mapToProperty: string, relationName: string, alias: string, queryBuilderFactory: (qb: SelectQueryBuilder<any>) => SelectQueryBuilder<any>): this;

/**
 * LEFT JOINs relation id and maps it into some entity's property.
 * Optionally, you can add condition and parameters used in condition.
 */
loadRelationIdAndMap(mapToProperty: string,
                     relationName: string,
                     aliasNameOrOptions?: string|{ disableMixedMap?: boolean },
                     queryBuilderFactory?: (qb: SelectQueryBuilder<any>) => SelectQueryBuilder<any>): this {

    const relationIdAttribute = new RelationIdAttribute(this.expressionMap);
    relationIdAttribute.mapToProperty = mapToProperty;
    relationIdAttribute.relationName = relationName;
    if (typeof aliasNameOrOptions === "string")
        relationIdAttribute.alias = aliasNameOrOptions;
    if (aliasNameOrOptions instanceof Object && (aliasNameOrOptions as any).disableMixedMap)
        relationIdAttribute.disableMixedMap = true;

    relationIdAttribute.queryBuilderFactory = queryBuilderFactory;
    this.expressionMap.relationIdAttributes.push(relationIdAttribute);

    if (relationIdAttribute.relation.junctionEntityMetadata) {
        this.expressionMap.createAlias({
            type: "other",
            name: relationIdAttribute.junctionAlias,
            metadata: relationIdAttribute.relation.junctionEntityMetadata
        });
    }
    return this;
}
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/query-builder/relation-id/RelationIdAttribute.ts

```
/**
 * Stores all join relation id attributes which will be used to build a JOIN query.
 */
export class RelationIdAttribute {

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public Properties
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Alias of the joined (destination) table.
     */
    alias?: string;

    /**
     * Name of relation.
     */
    relationName: string;

    /**
     * Property + alias of the object where to joined data should be mapped.
     */
    mapToProperty: string;

    /**
     * Extra condition applied to "ON" section of join.
     */
    queryBuilderFactory?: (qb: SelectQueryBuilder<any>) => SelectQueryBuilder<any>;

    /**
     * Indicates if relation id should NOT be loaded as id map.
     */
    disableMixedMap = false;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**can you try with this code -**

```
async getByAccountBill(
    accountBill: string,
    id?: number
  ): Promise<Object | undefined> {
    const userService = new UserService();
    const user = await userService.getById(id);

    const bills = await this.billRepository.find({
      where: {
        accountBill: Like(`${accountBill}%`),
        user: Not(`${user.id}`)
      },
      relations: ["user"],
      select: {
        user: {
          id: true,
          name: true
        }
      }
    });

    if (bills) {
      return bills;
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```